# elasticsearch only show where nested object has no values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have the following structure (simplified):

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "vendorStatuses": [
        {
            "id": 200,
            "status": "Open"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to find is records where there are no vendor statuses. We recently upgraded from elasticseach 1.x to 5.x and I'm having trouble converting to get this functionality back.

My old Nest query looked like this:

```
!Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses.First())
    .Filter(f2 => f2.Missing(y => y.Id)));
```

The new query (now that `Missing` isn't available) looks like this so far:

```
Query<PurchaseOrder>
    .Bool(z => z
        .MustNot(a => a
            .Exists(t => t
                .Field(f => f.VendorStatuses)
            )
        )
    );
```

Which generates this:

```
GET purchaseorder/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "vendorStatuses",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm still seeing results that have `vendorStatuses` records.

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried searching for `vendorStatuses.id` or other fields, but it's not working. When I try to reverse the logic and do a `must` i see no results. I also tried doing it as a `nested` but couldn't get any closer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query using `must_not` and `exists` is not a `nested` query like the 1.x query. I think you're looking for something like

```
var query = Query<PurchaseOrder>
    .Bool(z => z
        .MustNot(a => a
            .Nested(n => n
                .Path(p => p.VendorStatuses)
                .Query(nq => nq
                    .Exists(t => t
                        .Field(f => f.VendorStatuses)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

client.Search<PurchaseOrder>(s => s.Query(_ => query));
```

which yields

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "vendorStatuses"
              }
            },
            "path": "vendorStatuses"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#unary-negation-operator) to make the query more succinct too

```
var query = !Query<PurchaseOrder>
    .Nested(n => n
        .Path(p => p.VendorStatuses)
        .Query(nq => nq
            .Exists(t => t
                .Field(f => f.VendorStatuses)
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you so much! I was trying to do `Nested` and THEN `bool`, i didn't realize it was possible to do `bool` then `nested`, thanks!

Comment: No worries :) You can do `nested` with an inner `bool` query, if you have multiple `nested` queries

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that is far from ideal in my opinion. I created a new property on my `PurchaseOrder` model for `NumberOfStatuses`, then I just do a term search on that for value of `0`.

```
public int NumberOfStatuses => VendorStatuses.OrEmptyIfNull().Count();

Query<PurchaseOrder>.Term(t => t.Field(po => po.NumberOfStatuses).Value(0));
```